# Calling a function which returns a validation result and checking the condition | powershell

Tags: powershell, function

I'm trying to perform a simple validation in a function using powershell, i think the logic seems to be correct but the code isnt working as expected

```
$string = "abc,def,ghi,jkl,abc,mno,pqr"
$splitString = $string.Split(',')

function test{
    param(
        $input 
        )
    if ($input -eq "abc"){
        return "invalid"
        }
    else{
        return "valid"
        }

}
foreach ($item in $splitString) {
    if ((test -input $item) -eq "invalid") {
        continue
    }
    else{

        Write-Output $item
        }
}
```

The above code should skip abc while printing as the function validation return is set to be invalid which it isn't, I believe the logic is right here but happy to be proven wrong, **Thanks in advance**

Comment: tried to work with same logic in python, working as expected 
string = "abc,def,ghi,jkl,abc,mno,pqr"
split_string = string.split(",")

def test(input):
    if input == "abc":
        return "invalid"
    else:
        return "valid"

for item in split_string:
    result = test(item)
    if result == "invalid":
        continue
    else:
        print(item)

Comment: Choose another name for the `$input` parameter. `$Input` is a so-called [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3#input) and PowerShell _will_ overwrite its value.